# NIFI: Ingesting monthly dump from SQL query into SFTP server as CSV files

Tags: apache-nifi

I am in a situation where I would like to store data as respective monthly CSVs using SQL query into SFTP server.

For instance, my query is :

```
    select fooId, bar from FooBar 
where query_date>=20180101 and query_date<20180201 --(for the month of January 2018)
```

I would like to store it as `20180101_FooBar.csv` on to my SFTP server. Similarly, other files for other months follow the same process with different *query_date* interval.

Important consideration to make : `I have to store the *fooId* as MD5 Hash string.`

How may I automate this flow in NIFI?

Roughly, the flow that I foresee is:

```
*ExecuteSQL*(but not sure how to paramterize the counter for query_date) 
-> *ConvertAvroToJson* 
-> *EvaluateJsonPath* (to extract the fooID ) 
-> *HashContent* 
-> *MergeContent* 
-> *PutSFTP*
```

Please advicee on how I may take this forward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this case I could think of three approaches.

**Approach 1**: execute SQL query with MD5 function to get hash value of fooId:

[image]

Flow:

1. GenerateFlowFile //add startdate,enddate attributes

   ```
   startdate -> ${now():format("yyyyMM"):minus(1):append("01")}
   enddate   -> ${now():format("yyyyMM"):append("01")}
   ```
2. ExecuteSQL //select md5(fooId) foodId, bar from FooBar where

   ```
   query_date>=${startdate} and query_date<${enddate}
   ```

   Change the above query as per your source to get md5 hash value for column
3. ConvertRecord //convert Avro format to Json format
4. UpdateAttribute //change the filename
5. PutSFTP //store the file.

**Approach 2**: Create MD5 hash value in NiFi

[image]

Flow:

1. GenerateFlowFile //add startdate,enddate attributes

   ```
   startdate -> ${now():format("yyyyMM"):minus(1):append("01")}
   enddate   -> ${now():format("yyyyMM"):append("01")}
   ```
2. ExecuteSQL //select fooId, bar from FooBar

   where query_date>=${startdate} and query_date

   change the above query as per your source to get md5 hash value for column
3. ConvertRecord //convert Avro format to Json format
4. SplitJson //split the array of json into individual flowfiles
5. EvaluateJsonPath //extract all the key values as flowfile attributes except for fooId key.
6. EvaluateJsonPath //overwrite the flowfile content with fooId value
7. HashContent //get the hash value for the flowfile content with MD5 algorithm
8. AttributesToJson //recreate the json message with new hash md5 value
9. MergeContent //create json array with defragement strategy
10. UpdateAttribute //change the filename
11. PutSFTP ////store the file.

Another way is to **write a script** that can parse the json array messages and create `md5 hashvalue` for the `fooId` key and write the json message with the new md5 hashvalue.

I uploaded both approaches [Approach1](https://github.com/shureddy/NiFiTemplates/blob/master/Approach1_Execute_SQL_query_with_MD5_function_to_get_hash_value_of_fooId.xml) and [Approach2](https://github.com/shureddy/NiFiTemplates/blob/master/Approach2_Create_MD5_hash_value_in_NiFi.xml) templates, Save and Upload to NiFi instance for more reference and use the approach that best fits for your case.